# Batch Files too Big to Read

Tags: file, batch-file, size, byte

I'm using a batch program to get the size of files and I've encountered a problem, when the size is over a certain number of bytes it comes up with an error saying numbers a limited to 32-bits of precision. I've tried a way around this by making it kibobits and mebibits but as soon as the program determines that a file is of the certain size it just refuses to do anything.

```
@echo off
set kbno=0
set mbno=0
set var=(this would be the output of the file size)
:kbcheck
if /i %var% GTR 1024 (
goto 10kbcheck
) else (
goto setsize
)
:10kbcheck
if /i %var% GTR 10240 (
goto 50kbcheck
) else (
set /a kbno+=1
set /a var=%var%-1024
goto kbcheck
)
:50kbcheck
if /i %var% GTR 51200 (
goto 100kbcheck
) else (
set /a kbno+=10
set /a var=%var%-10240
goto kbcheck
)
:100kbcheck
if /i %var% GTR 102400 (
goto 500kbcheck
) else (
set /a kbno+=50
set /a var=%var%-51200
goto kbcheck
)
:500kbcheck
if /i %var% GTR 512000 (
goto mbcheck
) else (
set /a kbno+=100
set /a var=%var%-102400
goto kbcheck
)
:mbcheck
if /i %var% GTR 1048576 (
set /a mbno+=1
set /a var=%var%-1048576
goto kbcheck
) else (
set /a kbno+=500
set /a var=%var%-512000
goto kbcheck
)
:setsize
set size=%var%
echo %mbno% mebibits %kbno% kibibits %size% bits
pause
```

But the error pretty much renders this useless

Comment: Could you give us a snippet of your code?

Comment: Um "batch file" does not really specify what kind of script we're talking about. Also, some code would be nice.

Comment: @MarcusMüller - "batch file" on Stack Overflow refers to the Windows command language. Read the tag.

Comment: What OS are you using? You might be able to throw a PowerShell one-liner in your batch code, since it can handle numbers much larger than batch's upper limit of 2^32.

Comment: @SomethingDark Windows 7

Comment: @SomethingDark uh, sorry then. I must admit I was assuming he OP referring to the windows command shell, but I was too dumb to take a look at the tag. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

It can be read on description for command [set](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) on [ss64.com](http://ss64.com/):

> The numbers must all be within the range of 32 bit signed integer numbers (-2,147,483,648 through 2,147,483,647) to handle larger numbers use PowerShell or VBScript.

So you have to recode your batch file as PowerShell or VBScript script to be able to calculate with a size value of a file larger than 2 [GiB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibibyte).

It would be possible to handle also large file sizes beyond [LONG_MAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limits.h) in a batch file as by default environment variables are strings and not integers.

Therefore a file size string with less than 10 characters in length, i.e. with a maximum of 9 digits - 0 to 999999999, can be directly processed.

But a longer file size string could contain an integer being greater than 2147483647 and must be therefore split into 2 integer strings.

All operations must be done with those 2 integer strings similar to what a C/C++/C# programmer would do when using 2 unsigned long variables for 64-bit operations.

Here is a little batch script demonstrating how to check if a number is too large for being processed as signed 32-bit integer.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "Number=0"
set /P "Number=Please enter an unsigned integer number: "

set "DigitsLow=%Number:~-9%"
if "%DigitsLow%"=="%Number%" goto MaxBits31

set "DigitsHigh=%Number:~0,-9%"

if %DigitsHigh% EQU 1 goto MaxBits31
if %DigitsHigh% EQU 2 (
    if %DigitsLow% LEQ 147483647 goto MaxBits31
)

echo %Number% must be processed special because this
echo number is too large for a signed 32-bit integer.
goto EndBatch

:MaxBits31
echo %Number% can be processed as signed 32-bit integer.

:EndBatch
endlocal
```

Note: This demo batch code does not contain any code to detect wrong user input like something different than a number is entered by the user, or a negative number, or a real long sequence of digits.

How to best process a file size with a value greater than 2^31-1 depends on what you want to do with the file size information.

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I wrote a Decimal to PowerOf1024 conversion program that manage this conversion. [Here it is](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5270&p=31689#p31689):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem DecimalToPowerOf1024.bat bigNumber
rem Decimal to power-of-1024 base conversion of an unlimited size decimal number 
rem Antonio Perez Ayala

rem Values to try:  1024  1048576  1073741824  1099511627776  1125899906842624
rem 1152921504606846976  1180591620717411303424  1208925819614629174706176
rem 1237940039285380274899124224  1267650600228229401496703205376

rem Divide the number in 9-digits groups, eliminating left zeros in each group
set number=%1
set groups=0
:nextGroup
   set group=%number:~-9%
   for /L %%a in (1,1,8) do if "!group:~0,1!" equ "0" set group=!group:~1!
   set /A groups+=1
   set group[%groups%]=%group%
   set number=%number:~0,-9%
if defined number goto nextGroup

rem Convert the 9-digits groups to power-of-1024 values
set /A bitPos=0, PowerOf1024=0, PowerOf1024[0]=0
:nextBinaryDigit
   rem Divide the 9-digits groups by 2 
   set carry=0
   for /L %%i in (%groups%,-1,1) do (
      set /A term=carry*1000000000+group[%%i], group[%%i]=term/2, carry=term%%2
   )
   rem Insert remainder in current PowerOf1024 value, in right-to-left order
   set /A "PowerOf1024[%PowerOf1024%]+=carry<<bitPos, bitPos+=1"
   rem If current PowerOf1024 value completed: pass to next one
   if %bitPos% equ 10 set /A bitPos=0, PowerOf1024+=1 & set PowerOf1024[!PowerOf1024!]=0
   rem If last (most significant) group was completely converted: eliminate it
   if !group[%groups%]! equ 0 set /A groups-=1
   rem And pass to convert the rest of 9-digits groups
if %groups% gtr 0 goto nextBinaryDigit

rem Remove the last (most significant) PowerOf1024 value if it is zero
if !PowerOf1024[%PowerOf1024%]! equ 0 set "PowerOf1024[%PowerOf1024%]=" & set /A PowerOf1024-=1

set PowerOf1024
```

For example:

```
C:\> DecimalToPowerOf1024.bat 1267650600228229401496703205376
PowerOf1024=10
PowerOf1024[0]=0
PowerOf1024[10]=1
PowerOf1024[1]=0
PowerOf1024[2]=0
PowerOf1024[3]=0
PowerOf1024[4]=0
PowerOf1024[5]=0
PowerOf1024[6]=0
PowerOf1024[7]=0
PowerOf1024[8]=0
PowerOf1024[9]=0
```

You may use this conversion and then get the file size as: `%PowerOf1024[3]% GB + %PowerOf1024[2]% MB + %PowerOf1024[1]% KB + %PowerOf1024[0]% bytes`